# ¿Como añado símbolos de depuración en un archivo .aab subido a google play console?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console

Al revisar una app en google play console me sale este error:

> Este App Bundle contiene código nativo, pero no has subido símbolos de depuración. Te recomendamos que subas un archivo de símbolos para facilitar el análisis y la depuración de los errores ANR y bloqueos.

Desarrollo en react native y genero el archivo con expo.io y el comando:

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

No sé a qué hace referencia y que hay que hacer para solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión del SDK usas?

Comment: La versión SDK 29.

Comment: Muy antigua me parece. [Expo va por el SDK 38](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-ab6cd30ca2ee). Google Play [pide API level 29](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) en su caso (cosas diferentes)

Comment: Vale gracias voy a actualizar ...

Comment: Recomiendo ir subiendo SDK de Expo uno a uno, hay un artículo del blog para cada paso. Muchos son triviales, otros dan más trabajo

Comment: He actualizado expo y el sdk ahora tiene el ultimo el 39.0.0. En app.json he añadido: "sdkVersion": "39.0.0" Después de realizar expo build:android -t app-bundle y subirlo a Google Play Console me sigue dando ese mensaje de aviso y también indica que el SDK objetivo es el 29, pero creo que eso indica el SDK mínimo para ejecutar la app. Un vez subido el .aab aparece un menú con 3 puntitos donde hay una opción para subir un .zip con los símbolos de depuración nativos. Vamos, que sigo igual. XD

Comment: @JuanEnriqueGarcíaSancho pudiste agregar los símbolos de depuración? tengo el mismo problema, saludos

Comment: No es un error, es una advertencia.